# Need ideas for a compression algorithm

Tags: compression

**Background:** I'm making a web-based avatar generation system, where a user can select pieces for his avatar (like body, background, eyes, mouth, jacket, pants, etc.) and then a picture is generated from these selections. For performance reasons I then intend to do the following: from the list of selected items generate a filename which contains their IDs and save the picture under this filename. Then, when a request comes for a picture, the webserver will serve it directly. If a picture is not found, the 404-handler will generate it. And here then is the problem:

**Question:** I would like to compress a list of integers in as short a string as possible, consisting only of ASCII characters (usable for filenames and URLs). The integers will be unique, and greater than 0 (0 itself will not be among them). I expect that there might be around 20 of them and they would not exceed 200, but that is only a guess (though I'd be surprised if they got past 500). The order is not important.

What do you recommend I should do?

**Update:** Whoops, it seems I have made a fundamental mistake. I wanted to avoid storing every generated avatar in the DB, instead storing all necessary information in the filename. This way I hoped to avoid unnecessary use of DB and thus increased performance. However today it struck me that people might want to *change* their avatars, and expect them to update everywhere where they've been used. Thus, the filename has to be constant. This then leaves just one option - I'll have to save info about the avatar in the DB. And then I might as well use GUIDs or some other random strings for the filenames.

Thank you for your help, everyone, and sorry for the false alarm. :(

Comment: create a mapping from 'avatar combined components' key to filename; and then use a GUID for the filename. No compression algorithm required.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the integers (9 bits per item) into an array of bytes, and then encode the result in [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: base64url variant doesn't have /

Comment: by his estimate of 20 integers with a range of 200 each, I estimate 153 bits. That can be encoded in Base64 in 26 characters. Seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score -1):

Not really clear on what you're looking for; would ASCII-85 work? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85

As in, each integer encoded to a UTF-8 character, the characters made into a string, then encode the resulting string in base-85.

As Doug Currie points out, ASCII-85 is not a good choice. Any of the base64 variants that don't use the forward slash is preferable.

Comment: Ascii85 is a good suggestion, but Base64 makes it easier to use the result as a file name.

Comment: ah, that's true. forward slashes and angle brackets are problematic :^}

Comment: How does this compress the data and make the resulting string as short as possible?

Answer (score -1):

One option might be to take the md5 of the combination of numbers to get a 128-bit number. You can then hex encode that into a 32-character ASCII string, or base64 encode it into a 22-character one.

You can now guarantee that all file names are a fixed size and there is only a vanishingly small chance of a collision.

This saves a small amount of space for each filename (128 bits instead of 180) and it is independent of the number of values and range of each value, so even if you go beyond 20 items or a maximum value of 500 it won't affect the filename length.

Comment: However I won't be able to decode the IDs from the filename anymore.

Comment: Ah. It wasn't clear that you wanted to do the reverse lookup too. It seemed from your question that you just wanted to map a set of integers to a filename. In that case, don't hash it :)